# Making a server for a webapp

Tags: web-applications, hosting

me and some friends in school have to do a project and we decided to make a simple webapp. Nothing fancy, just something with accounts and simple DB queries. We are at the stage where we have to decide what we use to host all of this.

Here are some of our options:
- Hosting on a PI
- We have Github Student (https://education.github.com/pack)

We're all really new to this so could somebody recommend us on what to do? We have no Idea how to do this.